Zumero sync fails to retrieve all the data
I'm facing a strange issue with an Android app that syncs to a remote server.
In order to track down the problem, I've built a simple app that does only the synchronization. My sync function stops with the following error (the first two rows are infos from Zumero callback, the following is the complete exception):
Total size: 1626397 bytes
Transferred : 1626392 bytes

Error 300 (sglib)[ZSS 3.3.0.4342 + Android SQLite (libe_sqlite3.so)3.31.13.31.13.31.13.31.1]: Java Exception during network call: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:398)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:372)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:248)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:288)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:347)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.zumero.internal.ZumeroUtils.DoNetworkCall(ZumeroUtils.java:167)

    src/core/client/zum_http__android_jni.c:214
    src/core/client/zum_http__android_jni.c:290
    src/core/client/zum_sync.c:7398
    src/core/client/zum_sync.c:11963
    src/core/client/zum_sync.c:13063
    src/core/client/zum_sync.c:13527

The total size is never the same on every call, but it could be dued to some header difference. But the transfer stops some bytes before the end (sometimes few bytes, sometimes more); occasionally the transfer completes correctly (let's say one on ten/fifteen sync), but I cannot see an evident correlation between the total size and the correct complete. After that, the subsequent synchronizations can fail or not fail, even with small packets (for example the last three syncs - made while I'm writing this post - fail with a total size of 1111 bytes and a transferred size of 1110 bytes).
Zumero server is 3.2.1.4172, running on IIS 8.5.9600.16384 on a Windows Server 2012R2; Zumero client is the same release. The app is an empty Android app compiled on VS2022.
Surely I'll try on one of our internal server, in order to see if the issue persist and possibly provide a concrete test case (I cannot share my customer data...), and also generating the same app under Android Studio, although this is only a test, it's not feasible porting the entire app on Android Studio.
This is the code snippet that calls the sync function; the presence of the callback function has no influence on the results, it just writes the two first lines with the packet total/transferred size.
        private string syncAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                ZumeroClient.Sync(_dbFile, "", "http://***.***.***.***:1045", REMOTE_SCHEMA, SYNC_SCHEMA, "user", "password", SyncCallback);

                return "OK";
            }
            catch (ZumeroException zEx)
            {
                return zEx.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception genEx)
            {
                return genEx.ToString();
            }
        }


Last info: all the tests were done on the emulator, on an API30 device. I've had the occasion to find a real device (Zebra MC93, API29), and two consecutive sync from empty database worked like a charm, so it appears as the emulator having an internal bug or some other issue on the http communication. I've had the same problem with FTP transfers.
